# AppExchange component "Cell" is not working

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps, appexchange

I need an Excel-like behaviour in my lightning

So I have installed AppExchange component [Cell](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000000q5A3EAI).

It is not working - I am getting this error while adding the component in my Lightning App Builder, and also while adding it to the regular VisualForce sample page that comes with the app:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'DragToScroll' of undefined
> throws at /resource/Cell_handsontable_full_min_js:9:24519

Any solution would be highly appreciated

Thanks

Comment: 2 stars out of 5 reviews with major problems listed in those reviews and not updated for 18 months when Lightning is changing? Not promising.

Comment: I agree, but I really want an excel table, I can see they use [handsontable](https://handsontable.com/), so I can use that also, but I would love not to work a lot for getting that...

Comment: Your solution will have to be [Locker Service](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer16/release-notes/rn_lightning_locker.htm) compatible eventually so best to also research if handsontable is/will be compatible.

Comment: Yes, I have disabled the locker service and this error disappears (I have a different error now, but this is a different story), Thanks Keith